# Date format conversion adding extra year

Tags: java, date

I need to format my input date string.

Input date string : `28-01-1983(dd-MM-yyyy)`

Expected date string : `1983-01-28 (yyyy-MM-dd)`

I have used below program. But I am not getting correct output.

```
public static String formateDate(String oldFormat, String newFormat, String date) {
        final String OLD_FORMAT = oldFormat;
        final String NEW_FORMAT = newFormat;

        String oldDateString = date;
        String newDateString = null;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
            Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
            sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
            newDateString = sdf.format(d);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newDateString;
}
```

Calling method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String formatDob = formateDate("MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-dd-MM", "28-01-1983");
        System.out.println("Formated DOB:"+formatDob);
```

}

Right now I am getting output : `Formated DOB:1985-01-04`

Why my code produce wrong output? I am using JDK 1.7

Comment: Old format should be 'dd-MM-yyyy'. There is not a month 28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing month as `28` in your old format which says `(12 + 12 + 4)` means `April` month of the upcoming third year.

So, your old format(`MM-dd-yyyy`) will parse date as `(1983 + 2 years) = 1985` and 4<sup>th</sup> month of the third year which is `April` so you will have date `1st April 1985`. Your old date format should be `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first part of the conversion

You have format of `MM-dd-yyyy` and you have the date string of `28-01-1983`

As there is not a month 28 I suggest that the format should be `dd-MM-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
formateDate("MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-dd-MM", "28-01-1983");
```

to

```
formateDate("MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-dd-MM", "01-28-1983");
```

Your were passing date in place month.